# PHP detect string encoding from different languages

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I've some text files that contain some lines of text that are encoded in differents languages.
As example, I can have one line encoded in cirillic CP (CP855 or CP856) and another one in greek CP (CP1253) also in the same file, I can have lines in French or plain English or German...

To be more specific, my problem is that I can't know previously what exact kind of encoding is used for each line, so I need to identify the encoding to apply an iconv conversion to utf-8

I already read dozens and dozens (I'm stuck on this problem for almost 3 days now...) of previous questions and answers from Stackoverflow about this topic (or similar one) but none of these are able to solve my problem.

My goal is to find the correct CP or ISO definition to use with iconv, something like:

```
iconv('CP1253','UTF-8', $text)
```

or

```
iconv('ISO-8859-7','UTF-8', $text)
```

where CP1253 and ISO-8859-7 are the Greek Code page / ISO definition and the $text variable contain Greek text.

I already test different solutions, starting from my own code to various libraries.

my initial test:

```
$text = 'åíôõðùóéáêÝò';
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), true);
if (! is_bool($encoding)) {
    $item = iconv(
        $encoding,
        'UTF-8',
        $text
    );
}
```

This solution simply doesn't work even if one of the most suggested on StackOverflow.

`mb_detect_encoding` is totally unusefull for me (but seem not only for me judging from other comments that I found), sometime return simply false, other return as useless "ANSI".

In my example above what seem "garbage text" (because as far as I undestand, the file that I receive are all encoded in CP1251 Ansi latin 1) can be converted to "εντυπωσιακές" using CP1253 but  mb_detect_encoding return simply... false on the source string.

To be sure that data that I receive must be really converted and is not garbage text, I found one I was sure of the encoding (is the example text above) and I've tried to convert "manually" using below code:

```
$text = 'åíôõðùóéáêÝò';
iconv('CP1253','UTF-8', $text);
```

This return the correct text in Greek. If I try to use `mb_detect_encoding` on this text, I simply receive... false. As side note, also using ISO-8859-7 instead CP1235 work as expected.

I also try some external library but none works... like:

https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8

https://github.com/onnov/detect-encoding

and others, but these working partially or not working at all..

I also found an excellent library written in Python that seem work pefectly for any of my test cases and install a command that can be used to detect the encoding, but is impossibile for me to use it on every single line of all files that I can receive (thousands each months, each file from 20 to 250 lines)
The library is called chardet and can be found here https://github.com/chardet/chardet, I leave here the link if some one need it.

So, there is a way to solve this problem? someone kwow how ti solve this (seem) very common problem?

**Update 1**

1. Just to be more clear, I remove the "library request", **my request is for a real and stable php solutions that allow to identify charset of unknown text encoding not a library request suggestion, the library idea come on my mind because something similar exists in another language and is given only to explain my needed**.
2. My example work as expected on different setup, from php 7 to 7.4.x but
   to be more specific, I leave also the hex definition of the string as requested on comments, this is the complete example as hex string so is not influenced in any way from the posting in an html form:

```
$text = hex2bin('E5EDF4F5F0F9F3E9E1EADDF20D');
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), true);
if (! is_bool($encoding)) {
    $text = iconv(
        $encoding,
        'UTF-8',
        $text
    );
}

var_dump($encoding);
var_dump(iconv('CP1253','UTF-8', $text));
```

Above example return the exact result of previous example if used on a real php system and also on online-editor as suggested on one of comment below.
This can be seen as perfect example that mb_detect_encoding is not working as expected.

Comment: See here [LINK](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/12fa27f946a1c630adaa3687fc990fceb3c911e2) your coding example does seem to work correctly, showing the text as UTF-8. It's hard as many encodings can be interpreted as simply subsets of valid UTF-8 encodings

Comment: If this script doesn't work on your system then there may be some form of issue with your system wide PHP mb_string settings, somewhere.

Comment: This is a fundamentally hard problem, as [the FAQ for that Python library](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html) explains. `mb_detect_encoding` is implemented in [about 100 lines of C code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl/mbfilter.c#L285), whereas the Python library has [several thousand lines just modelling the Greek language](https://github.com/chardet/chardet/blob/master/chardet/langgreekmodel.py), so it should not be surprising that it gives better results. You could try to port the Python library, or you could write some Python or C code.

Comment: @Martin thank you but your example is wrong. Try with a real php installation. Your suggestion is a perfect example of how mb_detect_encoding  is unusefull. The text in my example is NOT UTF-8 encoded, is a CP1253 that is an ANSI standard not an unicode one. Also your on-line editor have something wrong because my iconv example doesn't work at all giving an error about the string itself. If you execute the code on a real 7.4 PHP setup you will see that the mb_detect_encoding fail and the "manual" iconv example work as expected.

Comment: Posting examples of character encodings is really hard, because if you post them as text, they will be text *in the encoding of this website*, which is UTF-8. If you really want a reproducible example, you'll need to specify the individual bytes. However, note that asking for recommendations of libraries is considered "off-topic" here, and my point above stands: this is a fundamentally hard problem, and your best bet is probably to adapt the tool you have found so that it's suitable for your use.

Comment: @Marco er, it's not *wrong*, it's a link to a working PHP sandbox script. It works. But it might not involve all the settings that you have on your system, because it's a sandbox. And because you haven't shared what's on your system. Edit: And IMSoP makes good points that are out of my pay grade! `:-D`

Comment: Every single-byte encoding is basically indistinguishable from any other single-byte encoding. Any sequence of bytes is "valid" in any of them. You need to decide on a human language level whether the characters you get from your interpreted byte sequence make any particular sense or not. Which means you need pretty complex natural language processing. PHP doesn't come with anything like that, and it's infeasible to invent it from scratch. So you *are* asking for a library ultimately.